# show errors not working properly in jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form in which if any errors are occurred then errors are displayed centrally above the form and also in the respective elements errors are displayed. But when I type on the input fields the errors are removed from the element but above the form the error headline is still displayed and the errors are not displayed.

[image: Form error message]

In the image, you can find the better description of the problem being faced.

Kindly help me on this.

```
$('#dsPatientForm').validate({
errorElement: 'span',
rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,
        },
        email: {
            required: true,

        },
        country: {
            required: true
        },
        zip: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
        terms: {
             required : true
        }
},
messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "Please enter firstname",
        },
        lastname: {
            required: "Please enter lastname",
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter the email",

        },
        country: {
            required: "Please select country"
        },
        zip: {
            required: "Please enter the postal code",
            digits: "Enter only digits"
        },
        terms: {
           required : "Please accept the terms"
      }
},//end messages
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       if (element.attr("name") == "country" ){
            error.insertBefore(element.parent().parent('.form-group'));
       }else{
           error.insertBefore(element.parent('.form-group'));
       }


},//end errorPlacement
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var summary = "Please correct the following errors: <br/>";
        $.each(errorList, function() { summary += " - " + this.message + "
<br/>"; });
        $("#sp").empty();
        $("#sp").html(summary);
        $("#sp").addClass("error-top mb15");


    this.defaultShowErrors();

},
highlight: function(element) {
     $(element).removeClass("error");
     $(element).addClass("err");
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
     $(element).removeClass("err");
}
});
```

Comment: Please put your code to better understanding.

Comment: please find the code above

Comment: I want to show the other leftout errors above the form where it is displaying "Please correct the following errors:", but the required email error is only displayed in the element not above the form on keyup. @DharmendraSingh

Comment: `showErrors` is not the correct approach for this because it does not fire when the element is valid.  See the linked answers above for more information.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I want display the errors both in element and also in a div above the form with a list then it cannot be done with showerrors function. 
Thanks for the information.@Sparky